# Running the same test on two different fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a test which currently runs with a single fixture like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def foo():
    return 'foo'


def test_something(foo):
    # assert something about foo
```

Now I am creating a slightly different fixture, say

```
@pytest.fixture
def bar():
    return 'bar'
```

I need to repeat the exact same test against this second fixture. How can I do that without just copy/pasting the test and changing the parameter name?

Comment: I couldn't be bothered to figure out the details, but this looks like it might be helpful:  https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example

Comment: @wim That looks like it might work for my purposes. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 16):

Beside the test generation, you can do it the "fixture-way" for any number of sub-fixtures applied dynamically. For this, define the actual fixture to be used as a parameter:

```
@pytest.fixture
def arg(request):
    return request.getfuncargvalue(request.param)
```

The define a test with am indirect parametrization (the param name `arg` and the fixture name `arg` must match):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('arg', ['foo', 'bar'], indirect=True)
def test_me(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Lets also define those fixtures we refer to:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo():
    return 'foo'

@pytest.fixture
def bar():
    return 'bar'
```

Observe how nicely parametrized and identified these tests are:

```
$ pytest test_me.py -s -v -ra
collected 2 items                                                                                

test_me.py::test_me[foo] foo
PASSED
test_me.py::test_me[bar] bar
PASSED
```

Comment: `getfuncargvalue` is deprecated. Is there a "modern" way to do this?

Comment: getfixturevalue()

Comment: From [pytest 5.1.0 release notes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/changelog.html#removals), use [`getfixturevalue`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue) instead.